# How to create circle or buffer of 1 KM around specified waypoint in arcGIS JAVA SDK?

Tags: javafx, arcgis, arcgis-runtime

I'm using this code snippet to draw circle, Circle shape is fine but circle covers even thousand km during zoom-out. I need to fix this circle around specified radius.

```
     private void addPointGraphic(double lat, double lng, float radius) {
           
        if (graphicsOverlay != null) {
            Viewpoint viewpoint = new Viewpoint(latitude, longitude, 12);
            final ListenableFuture<Boolean> viewpointSetFuture = mapView.setViewpointAsync(viewpoint, 5);
            SimpleMarkerSymbol pointSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.Style.CIRCLE, color, radius);
            pointSymbol.setOutline(new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.Style.SOLID, hexGreen, 1.5f));
            Point point = new Point(lng, lat, SpatialReferences.getWgs84());

            Graphic pointGraphic = new Graphic(point, pointSymbol);
            graphicsOverlay.getGraphics().add(pointGraphic);
         
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Java has many samples available for different workflows.
Perhaps the `Buffer` sample suits what you are trying to do:
https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-java/tree/master/geometry/buffer

Esri's GeoNet forums also have dedicated message boards for all the SDKs, so any perticular questions regarding the Java SDK might get more visibility from that community there:
https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-java/bd-p/arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-java-questions